# How to calculate spin density in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, spin-polarization

I would like to ask how to calculate spin density like shown in Fig 2(f) in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-29797-1) using Quantum ESPRESSO? A simple tutorial/example will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the calculation of spin density using QE? or how to plot such a figure using one of the modules (maybe pp.x) of QE?

Comment: i am asking about the calculation of spin density, is it using plot_num = 6 in pp.x or another way?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin would not have seen your response because you did not use the `@` character to ping him. I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani, i still need the answer